# Azure Data Factory Copy Activity for JSON to Table in Azure SQL DB

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a copy activity that takes a bunch of JSON files and merges them into a singe JSON.

[image]

[image]

I would now like to copy the merged single JSON to Azure SQL DB. Is that possible?

Ok, it appears to be working however the output in SQL is just countryCode and CompanyId

[image]

However, I need to retrieve all the financial information in the JSON as well

[image]

Comment: do all the merged files have the same json format?  If so you should be able to use a Copy Activity to do it.  If they have different formats then I wouldn't merge them together.

Comment: Yes all the merge files have the same format. Do you have an example showing the solution?

Comment: Hi Scott, I'm not sure if you read my question fully... The files have already been merged. I would like to know if I can copy the 'merged' json into our SQL DB?

Comment: Just create a Copy Activity from the json file to Sql database then.  If the format matches the db table then you don't need to specify the schema.  Of the copy activity has an option to automatically create the table for you matching the json schema.

Comment: I chose the option to automatically create the table but I keep on getting the message 'Table is required for Copy Activity'

Comment: it sounds like you didn't specify the table name?  Hard to tell without seeing the Sink settings for writing to database.

Comment: Even if you select auto create option, you need to specify the table name in the dataset. [Image](https://i.imgur.com/jQaiE3H.png)

Comment: Oh I see, Aswin.... thanks all. I'm a little tired now. Will test in the morning. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Azure Data Factory Copy Activity for JSON to Table in Azure SQL DB

I repro'd the same and below are the steps.

- Two json files are taken as source.
  [image]
- Those files are merged into single file using copy activity.
  [image]

[image]

- Then Merged Json data is taken as source dataset in another copy activity.

[image]

- In sink, dataset for Azure SQL db is created and Auto create table option is selected.

[image]

- In sink dataset, edit checkbox is selected and sink table name is given.
  [image]
- Once the pipeline is run, data is copied to table.

[image]

Comment: Aswin, this is amazing. Going to check this out now.

Comment: Hi Aswin, your solution appears to be working, but its not importing all the fields in the JSON

Comment: While copying the Merged JSON data to SQL Db using copy activity, In mapping tab , 1) Import Schema, 2) Toggle to the advanced editor. 3) Select the collection reference array value with which you want to iterate and extract data. 4) Give the names in the mapping for sink columns,if not available.
Refer this [MS doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-schema-and-type-mapping#hierarchical-source-to-tabular-sink)